# Session variable in PHP allows me to log in even though credentials are incorrect

Tags: php

I have a question about sessions. I noticed something unusual when I was testing my PHP code. Basically, I have two courses and the credentials are stored in their own database.

- Example: Course 1: Username: abc Password: 123, database table:
  flitpc
- Example: Course 2: Username: abc Password: 999, database table: itst

So the code below determines the login for the respective courses (both exactly same code for each course with the difference being the database table)

```
<?php   
// Initialize the session   
session_start();    
    
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page 
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){ 
  header("location: index");    
  exit; 
}   
    
// Include config file  
require_once "config.php";  
    
// Define variables and initialize with empty values    
$username = $password = ""; 
$username_err = $password_err = ""; 
    
// Processing form data when form is submitted  
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){   
    
    // Check if username is empty   
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){    
        $username_err = "Please enter username";    
    } else{ 
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);   
    }   
        
    // Check if password is empty   
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){    
        $password_err = "Please enter your password";   
    } else{ 
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);   
    }   
        
    // Validate credentials 
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){   
        // Prepare a select statement   
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM flitpcusers WHERE username = ?"; 
            
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){    
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters   
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);    
                
            // Set parameters   
            $param_username = $username;    
                
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement    
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){ 
                // Store result 
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);    
                    
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password    
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                       
                    // Bind result variables    
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);   
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){   
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){   
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session  
                            session_start();    
                                
                            // Store data in session variables  
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;   
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;  
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                              
                                
                            // Redirect user to welcome page    
                            header("location: index.php");  
                        } else{ 
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid    
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid";   
                        }   
                    }   
                } else{ 
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist   
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username";  
                }   
            } else{ 
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later."; 
            }   
            // Close statement  
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   
        }   
    }   
        
    // Close connection 
    mysqli_close($link);    
}   
?>
```

So here is the thing, I have both tabs open on my browser, 1 for course 1, other for course 2.

**Defect**

- Tab 1: I log into course 1 with its credentials, works fine, I don't log out.
- Tab 2: I log into course 2 with course 2 username (same username as course 1), but I also use course 1 password, it logs me in,
- Now if I log out of both courses and try the second bullet point above again, I can't log in.

So it's unusual and I want to know how to fix this and understand a little bit more about sessions as I think it's related to that.

**Update**

I have also found out it doesn't matter if usernames are different. It may be recognising the same password used for both login.

Comment: at first glance, you do not clear the session `$_SESSION["loggedin"] = false;` when login is incorrect or logout

Comment: Hmmm. I do have a logout.php file where if user logs out ,session destroyed, which is this: `<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Unset all of the session variables
$_SESSION = array();
 
// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();
 
// Redirect to login page
header("location: login");
exit;
?>`

Comment: But I will check this `$SESSION[Loggedin"]` to be clear. I am assuming you mean destroy the session using `session_destroy()`?  I tried just now putting it in the else statement following from the `$_SESSION{"loggedIn"]..`. if statement but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is never actually performed in tab 2. Because you already have a session you're redirected to the index when you hit this code block:

```
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page 
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){ 
  header("location: index");    
  exit; 
}
```

You need to save `course` somewhere in `$_SESSION` and check if an appropriate session not only exists but matches the course, otherwise authentication using table 1 credentials is indistinguishable from authentication using table 2 credentials.

EDIT:

After authentication save from where the authentication occurred:

```
// Store data in session variables  
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;   
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;  
$_SESSION["username"] = $username; 
$_SESSION["authenticated_from"] = "flitpcusers";
```

Then when you're checking if a $_SESSION exists also check if it's for the appropriate course, so:

```
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page 
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true && $_SESSION["authenticated_from"]==="flitpcusers"){ 
  header("location: index");    
  exit; 
}
```

This will prevent a table 1 authenticated session as being recognized as a table 2 session.

While the above will fix the strange behaviors you're observing I'd really look at redesigning your database scheme here. It's strange that I need to authenticate differently for different courses. Ideally I authenticate once and that authentication is used for any/all services under that identity. Look at Google: I don't have to login to Youtube then login to Gmail then login to Search, I log in *once* and then Google servers determine which services I have access to.

Comment: Makes sense, I just need to figure out how to save the course. Would you recommend if I use the url of the course as store that as the session? So I do session contains a string match of a url where the course name is mentioned?

Comment: Hmm.. tried a few things but still not working, wonder if best if I can see a code snippet on what you're referring to as guidance :)

Comment: Awesome it worked. Thank you very much. I do understand from your point of view ( I didn't write the original design of this). The thing is, we are selling thee courses individually and each course has its own access for the user. So I didn't want it where a user is able to purchase a single course but then is able to use their credentials for the other course.

Comment: Additionally, consider adjusting your session variables to store authentication (and other information) specifically for the course required.  For example, instead of $_SESSION['loggedin'] change the references to $_SESSION['flitpcusers']['loggedin'] (both on the assignment and checking of the variables).  This will allow you to have multiple applications/courses living at the same root URL.  This will also allow users to be logged into two different courses at the same time without continually overwriting each others session information (not sure if that is a requirement though).

Answer (score 0):

You should use two different browser. Not the same browser.

Because browser hold session against respected web address, it doesn't metter how many tabs you have, all tabs will send same session id.

Suppose If you have logged in google chrome browser and you open another tab and hit the same web address, then the browser will request to server with the same Session Id and you will logged in automatically, because session is already exist.

Comment: Yes, but they're two different courses, they have two different urls.

Comment: Do you mean the base url are totally different? Can you give the two links?

Comment: Yep, the two links: https://metis-online.com/itst-998372318/login and https://metis-online.com/flitpc-998372319/login

Comment: It looks that your base urls are same which is metis-online.com so you can not log in with same session variable with the same browser. You can change the session index name for different tables login otherwise you have to use different browser.

Comment: Can you show me by code on what you mean by your last comment, the session index tables. One course points to table known as 'flitpc' and other 'itst' (view sql query in answer as example)